# TypeError: "path" is not defined: undefined NodeJS Serialport return function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, undefined, node-serialport

Hello i am trying to check the usb ports for detecting arduino usb port. So here is my

```
    function detectArdu() {
  detector.list().then(ports => {
    ports.forEach(function(port) {
    
      var searchString = port.manufacturer;
      var lookfor = "arduino";
      searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    
      if (searchString.indexOf(lookfor)>=0) {
        console.log(port.path);
        startSystem(port.path);
      }
    });
  });
}

detectArdu();

function startSystem(arduPortName) {
  try {
    test = new SerialInstance.SerialPort(arduPortName, {
      baudrate: 9600,
      dataBits: 8,
      parity: 'none',
      stopBits: 1,
      flowControl: false
    });
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Here is my console.log data:

```
TypeError: "path" is not defined: undefined
    at new SerialPortStream (C:\Users\gny\Desktop\jammer_socket_server\node_modules\@serialport\stream\dist\index.js:50:19)
    at new SerialPort (C:\Users\gny\Desktop\jammer_socket_server\node_modules\serialport\dist\serialport.js:13:9)
    at startSystem (C:\Users\gny\Desktop\jammer_socket_server\jammer_server.js:31:12)
    at C:\Users\gny\Desktop\jammer_socket_server\jammer_server.js:21:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\gny\Desktop\jammer_socket_server\jammer_server.js:13:11
```

So i tried different ways and i'm not good at NodeJS is there anyone know how to fix this error ?

Note: I'am from Turkey and my english maybe not good sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `path` key to SerialPort init, i.e

```
const port = new SerialPort({
  path: '/dev/tty-usbserial1',
  baudRate: 9600,
})
```